Access to XMLHttpRequest X from origin Y has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check
Access to XMLHttpRequest X from origin Y has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I am running into CORS issues when trying to deploy an application to a cloud server.

I managed to fix this problem when I was testing the application on my local machine (everything communicating via localhost)
I believe I also fixed the issue when I was using just ip addresses and the application was deployed to the cloud (can't be totally certain about this - it was late last night when I was trying to deploy it)
I now have a domain name, and I am now certainly having trouble with CORS

Archetecture
There is a server in the cloud which hosts the frontend and the backend of this system. The frontend is written using React+Vite, and is deployed as a static site using nginx on port 80.
The backend is written using Python+FastAPI, and is deployed inside a Docker container running on the same server. It exposes port 5555 for the API.
CORSMiddleware is enabled in FastAPI application:
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

origins = [
    'http://localhost',
    'http://localhost:80',
    'http://localhost:5555',
    'http://my-domain.co.uk',
    'http://my-domain.co.uk:80',
    'http://my-domain.co.uk:5555',
]

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=['*'],
    allow_headers=['*'],
)

I am not totally sure which of these ports are required.
This is my understanding of how the CORS system works:

The browser makes a request to the frontend at my-domain.co.uk:80.
Nginx returns the html, css and JS to the browser
Some of the JS contains code to make an axios request to my-domain.co.uk:5555/api/something
The browser sees this as a cross origin request but makes the request anyway
The backend server (FastAPI) receives the request to my-domain.co.uk:5000/api/something from my-domain.co.uk:80
(I guess the browser must send the information about which website originally gave it the javascript to make the next request?)
I'm guessing the browser then needs to do the pre-flight check by sending something to the FastAPI backend, and that the FastAPI backend must reply with the CORS headers
This doesn't seem to be happening
I would then guess if the browser did get back the CORS headers correctly, this would tell the browser that it is safe to make the full request to the backend to get the required data?

Have I understood the process by which CORS works correctly?
I have looked at some information in the "Network" tab of the developer tools in Chrome. I can't find any headers which look like Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
What might be causing these to be missing?



It's a pre-flight request, the browser makes it before it makes the main request. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS is a good overview.

@jonrsharpe I've already read this page

I hope this answer is able to help someone else.
The first thing to note: How to find the Headers information associated with the request.
As can be seen in the below screenshot, the relevant Headers are shown in the API request. Put another way: Look at the information associated with the api request and not the original http request for the website static content.
Once you have found the appropriate Headers, you can check to see if the Access-Control-Allow-Origin address(es) are correct.
One of the values should match the Origin field in the Request Headers.
I have marked all of these things in the screenshot.

